# Need help understanding a DAE file and what is truly required

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, model, collada

Im currently trying to output a 3D model to a dae file. The current issue is that Blender (and other model viewers) will not open the file. I am not getting any errors from blender. I followed examples of dae online and I think I have everything needed. All I have to output right now is faces and vertices. Previously, I was outputting this to an obj without issues.

I cant figure out if I am missing something.

Down below I have an example of the dae file that is being output by my code. For our sanity, I removed the 4000 vertices and faces from the output shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLADA version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <contributor>
            <author>Justin (JDOG) Barren</author>
            <authoring_tool>RaxToDae File Ripper</authoring_tool>
        </contributor>
        <unit meter="1.000000"/>
        <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>
    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="F1" name="allModel">
            <mesh>
                <source id="allModel-vertex-positions">
                    <float_array id="ID2-array" count="14442"> [ ...lots of numbers... ] </float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor source="#ID2-array" count="4814" stride="3">
                            <param name="X" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Y" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Z" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <vertices id="allModel-vertices">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#allModel-vertex-positions">
                </vertices>
                <triangles count="4842">
                    <input semantic="VERTEX" offset="0" source="#allModel-vertices"/>
                    <p> [ ...lots of numbers... ] </p>
                </triangles>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>
    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#Scene"/>
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

This is my code to generate the file in c++.

```
void OutputHeader(ofstream& stream) {
    stream << "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" << endl;
    //stream << "<COLLADA xmlns=\"http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema\" version=\"1.4.1\">" << endl;
    stream << "<COLLADA version=\"1.4.1\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t<asset>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t<contributor>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t<author>Justin (JDOG) Barren</author>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t<authoring_tool>RaxToDae File Ripper</authoring_tool>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t</contributor>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t<unit meter=\"1.000000\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t<up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>" << endl;
    stream << "\t</asset>" << endl;
}

void OutputVertsAndFaces(ofstream& stream, string modelName, int vertCount, int faceCount, vector <float> verts, vector <short> faces) {
    stream << "\t<library_geometries>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t<geometry id=\"F1\" name=\"" << modelName << "\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t<mesh>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t<source id=\"" << modelName << "-vertex-positions\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t<float_array id=\"ID2-array\" count=\"" << vertCount << "\">" << endl; for (int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++) stream << verts[i] << " "; stream << "</float_array>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t<technique_common>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t\t<accessor source=\"#ID2-array\" count=\"" << vertCount/3 << "\" stride=\"3\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name=\"X\" type=\"float\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name=\"Y\" type=\"float\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<param name=\"Z\" type=\"float\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t\t</accessor>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t</technique_common>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t</source>" << endl;

    stream << "\t\t\t\t<vertices id=\"" << modelName << "-vertices\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t<input semantic=\"POSITION\" source=\"#" << modelName << "-vertex-positions\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t</vertices>" << endl;

    stream << "\t\t\t\t<triangles count=\"" << faceCount << "\">" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t<input semantic=\"VERTEX\" offset=\"0\" source=\"#" << modelName << "-vertices\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t\t<p>"; for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) stream << faces[i] << " "; stream << "</p>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t\t</triangles>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t\t</mesh>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t</geometry>" << endl;
    stream << "\t</library_geometries>" << endl;

    stream << "\t<scene>" << endl;
    stream << "\t\t<instance_visual_scene url=\"#Scene\"/>" << endl;
    stream << "\t</scene>" << endl;
}

void OutputEndHeader(ofstream& stream) {
    stream << "</COLLADA>";
}
```

Comment: I'd check if it's a valid xml and compare with a valid file, especially the format of the numeric literals that represent the vertices coordinates. Unrelated: I don't think using `std::endl` is a good practice, since causes a flush writing on file. I also think that you are probably writing a fake utf8 without BOM (usually it's not a problem)

Comment: @MatG do you recommend using `/n` instead of `std::endl`? How can I check the validity of the xml? I looked for an online validator but didnt find anything. Im also wondering about the use of `/t` instead just a single space. In other files I saw that indentation was done with spaces, but im using tabs. Does indentation matter?

Comment: I'd use `'\n'`. *xml* parsers shouldn't care about spaces and indentation (except verbatim text blocks).Have you tried to compare with a DAE correctly "digested" by blender? Just to check the decimal separator char etc